# Count byte length of string

Tags: javascript, performance, strings, utf-8

I am looking for some guidance and optimization pointers for my custom JavaScript function which counts the bytes in a string rather than just chars. The website uses UTF-8 and I am looking to maintain IE8 compatibility.

```
/**
 * Count bytes in string
 *
 * Count and return the number of bytes in a given string
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string
 * @return  int
 */
function getByteLen(normal_val)
{
    // Force string type
    normal_val = String(normal_val);

    // Split original string into array
    var normal_pieces = normal_val.split('');
    // Get length of original array
    var normal_length = normal_pieces.length;

    // Declare array for encoded normal array
    var encoded_pieces = new Array();

    // Declare array for individual byte pieces
    var byte_pieces = new Array();

    // Loop through normal pieces and convert to URL friendly format
    for(var i = 0; i <= normal_length; i++)
    {
        if(normal_pieces[i] && normal_pieces[i] != '')
        {
            encoded_pieces[i] = encodeURI(normal_pieces[i]);
        }
    }

    // Get length of encoded array
    var encoded_length = encoded_pieces.length;

    // Loop through encoded array
    // Scan individual items for a %
    // Split on % and add to byte array
    // If no % exists then add to byte array
    for(var i = 0; i <= encoded_length; i++)
    {
        if(encoded_pieces[i] && encoded_pieces[i] != '')
        {
            // % exists
            if(encoded_pieces[i].indexOf('%') != -1)
            {
                // Split on %
                var split_code = encoded_pieces[i].split('%');
                // Get length
                var split_length = split_code.length;

                // Loop through pieces
                for(var j = 0; j <= split_length; j++)
                {
                    if(split_code[j] && split_code[j] != '')
                    {
                        // Push to byte array
                        byte_pieces.push(split_code[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // No percent
                // Push to byte array
                byte_pieces.push(encoded_pieces[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Array length is the number of bytes in string
    var byte_length = byte_pieces.length;

    return byte_length;
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript#answer-34920444) is an independent and efficient method to count UTF-8 bytes of a string. Note that the method may throw error if an input string is UCS-2 malformed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It would be a lot simpler to [work out the length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) yourself rather than to interpret the results of `encodeURI()`.

```
/**
 * Count bytes in a string's UTF-8 representation.
 *
 * @param   string
 * @return  int
 */
function getByteLen(normal_val) {
    // Force string type
    normal_val = String(normal_val);

    var byteLen = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < normal_val.length; i++) {
        var c = normal_val.charCodeAt(i);
        byteLen += (c & 0xf800) == 0xd800 ? 2 :  // Code point is half of a surrogate pair
                   c < (1 <<  7) ? 1 :
                   c < (1 << 11) ? 2 : 3;
    }
    return byteLen;
}
```

JavaScript implementations may use either UCS-2 or UTF-16 to represent strings.

UCS-2 only supports Unicode code points up to U+FFFF, and such Unicode characters occupy 1, 2, or 3 bytes in their UTF-8 representation.  This is not too tricky to handle.

However, as @Mac points out, UTF-16 surrogate pairs are a tricky special case.  UTF-16 extends UCS-2 by adding support for code points U+10000 to U+10FFFF, which UTF-16 encodes using a pair of code points.  The first code point of such a pair (called the "high surrogate") is in the range D800 to DBFF; it should always be followed by another code point (called the "low surrogate") is in the range DC00 to DFFF.  Observe that the UTF-8 representation of any character in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF would take 4 bytes.  Therefore, any surrogate pair in UTF-16 would translate to a 4-byte UTF-8 representation.  Or, we could say that whenever we encounter half of a surrogate pair (i.e., a code point is in the range from D800 to DFFF), just add two bytes to the UTF-8 length.

Comment: Nice, I saw similar but less clean code on the site I linked to, +1

Comment: I will give your suggestion a try as well but are the comments on [this site](http://forrst.com/posts/JavaScript_Get_the_exact_size_in_bytes_of_a_st-BZ5) relevant to the use of `charCodeAt()`?

Comment: Good question! The code at [forrst.com](http://forrst.com/posts/JavaScript_Get_the_exact_size_in_bytes_of_a_st-BZ5) is bogus. Although `ceil(log_256(charCode))` tells you the number of bytes it would take to represent `charCode`, there's nothing about UTF-8 in their `byteLength()` function. UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding scheme, and the few most-significant bits of every byte are necessary to indicate how many bytes form each character. Since any variable-length encoding scheme will have such padding, their `byteLength()` function gives a wrong answer for any encoding, including UTF-8.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! My test scenario was chopped down to .1 seconds with your code by the way, compared to ~3.2 respectively for @tomdemuyt , so it is definitely extremely efficient. I just have to wrap my head around these bitwise operators (I've never used them before) and then I can have rock-solid confidence in the script. According to Wikipedia, UTF-8 was ultimately restricted to a max of 4 bytes per char so is checking for 5 and 6 bytes fruitless or do you think UTF-8 will eventually extend to 5 and 6 bytes? I see your shorthand `if` statements will essentially never get to 5 and 6.

Comment: `1 << n` is simply a way to write 2^n. I think it's easier to understand `1 << n` than the magic numbers 128, 2048, 16384, etc.

Comment: The 4-byte limit for UTF-8 derives from the decision to [cap Unicode code points to U+10FFFF](http://www.unicode.org/faq/blocks_ranges.html#2). However, it takes no additional effort to add two more cases, so I would code defensively.

Comment: getByteLength( '' ) returns 6, but should be 4.

Comment: @Mac Addressed your bug report in Rev 2!

Comment: @200_success - Nice fix! 

Answer (score 8):

My 2 cents

- Please do not abbreviate words, choose short words or acronyms ( Len -> Length )
- Please lower camel case ( normal_val -> normalValue )
- Consider using spartan conventions ( s -> generic string )
- `new Array()` is considered old skool, consider `var byte_pieces = []`
- You are using `byte_pieces` to track the bytes just to get the length, you could have just kept track of the length, this would be more efficient
- I am not sure what `abnormal pieces` would be here:

`if(normal_pieces[i] && normal_pieces[i] != '')`

- You check again for these here, probably not needed:

`if(encoded_pieces[i] && encoded_pieces[i] != '')`

- You could just do `return byte_pieces.length` instead of

> ```
> // Array length is the number of bytes in string
> var byte_length = byte_pieces.length;
>
> return byte_length;
> ```

All that together, I would counter propose something like this:

```
function getByteCount( s )
{
  var count = 0, stringLength = s.length, i;
  s = String( s || "" );
  for( i = 0 ; i < stringLength ; i++ )
  {
    var partCount = encodeURI( s[i] ).split("%").length;
    count += partCount==1?1:partCount-1;
  }
  return count;
}
getByteCount("i ♥ js");
getByteCount("abc def");
```

You could get the sum by using `.reduce()`, I leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Finally, if you are truly concerned about performance, there are some very fancy performant js libraries [out there](http://mothereff.in/byte-counter#i%20%E2%99%A5%20js).

Comment: Thank you so much, looks like a lot of good stuff in your post. I will give them a go and see if I can get better performance numbers. I am not overly concerned about performance but my original code took ~6 seconds for 1200 iterations of 2400 Euro signs deduced by one char per iteration until I hit 1200 for my enforceMaxByteLength script and this code took ~3.8 so hopefully I can shave off a bit more

Comment: Your counter proposition is genius, it shaved another .6 seconds off my benchmark, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var b = str.match(/[^\x00-\xff]/g);
return (str.length + (!b ? 0: b.length));
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This only works for strings that consist solely of code points up to U+03FF. It fails to account for any Unicode characters whose UTF-8 representation requires 3 or more bytes.